# indexing list of tuples of tuple without loop

Tags: python

```
list1 = [((100,3),3,5,6),((200,3),3,5,6),((300,3),3,5,6),((400,3),3,5,6)]
```

I want to get first element of each tuple of tuples from the list.

I can achieve it easily using loop:

```
for i in list1:
  print(i[0][0])
```

But can for loop be avoided?

Comment: How would it function without some kind of loop?

Comment: @roganjosh sorry can't understand, I just want to extract those element in 100s.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop?

Comment: @krishna how do you expect it to be accomplished without a loop?

Comment: @klutt just out of curiosity. I was just not sure that this is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension, really same as loop.

```
[i[0][0] for i in list1]
```

Or, you can use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(list1).str[0].str[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I expected something like list1[:][0][0]. But list1[:] gives same as list1.  I thought there would be other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy`, and the only loops used will be implicit, and fast. But also less readable:

```
import numpy as np

>>> np.stack(np.array(list1)[:,0])[:,0]

array([100, 200, 300, 400])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run %%timeit on all the suggested methods here and this is the faster than most suggestions except one**

with numpy it gave:

> 31.6 µs ± 1.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

with pandas it gave:

> 475 µs ± 20.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

with regex the result is:

> 8.67 µs ± 50.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

with list comparison:

> 837 ns ± 8.81 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

A rather different and a faster way can be:

```
list1 = [((100,3),3,5,6),((200,3),3,5,6),((300,3),3,5,6),((400,3),3,5,6)]

list1=str(list1)
import re
d=re.findall("(?:\(\()(\d+)",list1)
[int(x) for x in d]
```

Output

```
[100, 200, 300, 400]
```

Comment: `d` is not defined

Comment: @user3483203 sorry fixed it

Comment: Also, you conveniently happened to avoid timing the list comprehension solution, which is *much* faster than a regex approach.

Comment: @user3483203 yes its in fact faster i will edit my code to include that, done edited

Comment: @user3483203 isn't it essentially for loop ?? just a different sytax doing the same thing ?

Comment: So it's an order of magnitude faster for the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is likely what you need. But for reference you can use `next` with an iterator, or `operator.itemgetter` for a functional solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def first_lazy(x): return map(itemgetter(0), x)
def first(x): return next(zip(*x))

%timeit [i[0][0] for i in list1]             # 44.9 ms
%timeit list(first_lazy(first_lazy(list1)))  # 68.6 ms
%timeit first(first(list1))                  # 78.9 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy `next(zip(*next(zip(*list1))))` :)

P.S.: here is some explanation.

First of all, I assume that you are using Python 3, so `zip` returns a generator-object, and thus subsequent calls to `next` are valid. So in order to group together the first entries (i.e. 2-element tuples) of each tuple in `list1`, we use `next(zip(*list1))`. In Python 2 you could do either `zip(*list1)[0]` or even `next(iter(zip(*list1)))`, since `zip` returns a list. Note that `zip` expects several iterable objects as input, so we are using `*` to pass each entry of `list1` (i.e. a 5-element tuple) as a separate argument to `zip`, so basically `zip(*list1)` means the same as

```
zip( ((100,3),3,5,6), ((200,3),3,5,6), ((300,3),3,5,6), ((400,3),3,5,6) )
```

Anyway, both in Python 3 and Python 2 the output after the first step will be the following:

```
((100, 3), (200, 3), (300, 3), (400, 3))
```

So now we have to group together the first entries of each tuple in the resulting sequence. Sounds familiar, doesn't it? Exactly, we already did it in the first step! So after applying `next(zip(*))` again, we will obtain the final answer:

```
(100, 200, 300, 400)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Agreed, will add a short explanation above.